# Codeblocks not running at all after installation

Tags: installation, code-blocks

Little history:

Codeblocks 10.05 used to run smoothly in my Ubuntu. Now, I downloaded the deb package of codeblocks 12.11 and installed. But mysteriously, it forgets my every modification every-time I close. So, I uninstalled the deb package, then autoremoved broken packages and then reinstalled codeblocks 10.05.

---

But I didn't get a happy ending. Now codeblocks is installing properly. But if I click on the icon of codeblocks, it is not opening or not even responding at all. I even tried re-installing, same issue.

Note: It's installing properly without any error message, just not running at all. No error message or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar happend to me. The right thing to do is try for a full reinstalation.

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge codeblocks
```

This will **delete all your configuration files** and remove used packages along with codeblocks like codeblocks-common, etc.

If you install again, it'll run with no visible erros, but chances are it'll not install codeblocks-contrib due to version incompatibility if your packages are broken like mine was. 
And trying to run codeblocks from will get you a "codeblocks: symbol lookup error"

The fix for me was to first, purge libcodeblocks0 which was broken for me

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libcodeblocks0
```

Then install it again with

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Comment: I have to do that once a month